# How find out name of ballot x mark in a unicode font with XeLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode, unicode-math

With XeLaTeX, I can obtain check and ballot x marks with `pifont`:

With `pifont`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\cmark & Yes
\\
\xmark & No
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: pifont's check mark and ballot x mark]

**Goal:** To use only Unicode characters in my XeLaTeX document to match those, by doing something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range={\checkmark,\ballotx}]
\newcommand{\cmark}{\checkmark}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ballotx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\cmark & Yes
\\
\xmark & No
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

That's OK for `\checkmark`, but I get an "Undefined control sequence" error for `\ballotx`.

I do realize that any given Unicode font might not have a particular symbol I want; that is *not* the real issue here.

**Question:** How does one find out the correct **name** to use for a "heavy ballot x" — or for that matter, any other particular symbol — to use with the `\setmathfont{...}[range[{...}]`? That is, a name akin to `\checkmark` (which does work if the font has it).

Whenever I try to identify a symbol by looking in descriptions of a Unicode characters, I see often multi-word names, e.g., "Unicode Character 'BALLOT X' (U+2717)". But that does not tell me what *name* to use for the character!

**Solution to `\cmark` and `\xmark` with XeLaTeX and OTF font:**

Thanks to help from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553109/13492, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553095/13492, and use of both the UnicodeChecker app and the `otfinfo -g` command, I have the following resolution:

```
% !TeX program =xelatexmk
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newfontfamily{\xcheckmarkfont}{LibertinusSerif-Regular.otf}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\scalebox{1.2}[1.4]{\rotatebox{-8}{\xcheckmarkfont\char"2714}}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\scalebox{1.2}[1.42]{\raisebox{-.1ex}{\xcheckmarkfont\char"2718}}}

\RequirePackage[names]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\greencheck}{\color{green!70!brown}{\cmark}}
\newcommand{\redx}{\color{red}{\xmark}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lc}
\cmark &  Yes
\\
\xmark & No
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: LibertinusSerif-Regular.otf check mark and ballot x mark]

**Request:**

Suggestions for improvement of the results, so as to more closely match the `pifont` output, will be very welcome!

Comment: The ballot x symbol isn't defined in unicode-math. See https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf for a complete list of symbols which are defined. See this answer for accessing the symbol by its hexcode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779234/unicode-characters-in-xelatex/56707992#56707992

Comment: @DonaldHosek: So then how, e.g., do I specify a particular Unicode font to use with `\char"2718`?

Comment: You can use `newunicodechar` to set the Unicode character active: `\newunicodechar{^^^^2718}{\xmark}`

Comment: If you’re scaling the marks, you probably want to load the font with a `Scale=` option rather than wrap it in a `\scalebox`.

Comment: You also want to enclose commands to set the font and color within a group, so they don’t bleed through and set the font and color of the text after it. Just add another set of outer braces around the body of the command.  Or use `\textcolor` instead of `\color`.

Comment: @Davislor: If I use `\newunicodechar{^^^^2718}{\xmark}`, how does XeLaTeX know which font I'm using? I.e., what do I gain or lose by using that?

Comment: @Davislor: Re using `Scale=` option when loading the font: notice that I'm using unequal vertical scaling as well as different horizontal and vertical scaling. I don't see how to achieve either of those with the `Scale=` option (refer to fontspec.pdf, Sec. 6.2.)

Comment: @murray Fair enough.