# How specify by Unicode number a particular character from another font (XeLaTeX)?

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode, unicode-math

The following defines commands `\cmark` and `\xmark`to produce the Unicode characters with codes U+2718 and U+2714, respectively.

**Question:**

Is there some simpler, or alternative, way that the following to specify an individual character, from a different font than the main one in use — when only one or two characters from that font are going to be used?

```
% !TeX program =xelatexmk
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

% How  create command for character that has Unicode U+2718?
\newfontfamily{\xmarkfont}{LibertinusMath-Regular.otf}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\xmarkfont\char"2718}
\newfontfamily{\cmarkfont}{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\xmarkfont\char"2714}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
Wrong & \xmark\\
Right & \cmark
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: x mark and check mark from separate fonts]

**Related:** [How find out name of ballot x mark in a unicode font with XeLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553072/how-find-out-name-of-ballot-x-mark-in-a-unicode-font-with-xelatex)

Comment: Why not just load the  `bbding` package and type  `\CheckmarkBold`  or `\XSolidBrush` ?

Answer (score 4):

You would really want to change the font inside a group, so the font change doesn’t bleed through to the text after it.  So,

```
\newcommand{\xmark}{{\xmarkfont\char"2718}}
```

You would define `\xmarkfont` as you did in your MWE, to a font that has it, probably scaled with `Scale=MatchUppercase`.

In math mode with `unicode-math`, you can set the font for a specific math character with the `range=` option of `\setmathfont`.

You can use `newunicodechar` to set a character active, which allows you to paste it into your source, e.g.

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{^^^^2718}{\xmark}
```

This lets you type either `\xmark`, ઞ, or `^^^^2718` and have it just work.

In XeLaTeX, you can theoretically use `ucharclasses` to set the font for all dingbats, or any other Unicode block.  As of July 2020, however, this package is broken and apparently unmaintained.

If you want to use the character from the current font if and only if the font has it, and fall back if and only if it does not, you would define the `\xmark` command as a conditional with `\iffontchar`.

In XeTEX, it is possible, but complicated, to insert commands (such as `\begingroup\symbolfont` and `\endgroup`) around a particular group of characters with [`\XeTeXinterchartoks`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/xetex/xetexref/xetex-reference.pdf#11).  This lets you type them in and select the font correctly without explicit markup, and is what `ucharclasses` is supposed to be doing.

Comment: :: But apparently, Unicode U+2718 does not have a name in at least some of the fonts that include it.

Comment: This answer does not explain how to specify the particular font from which the character will be taken. That's precisely the underlying problem. The default font I'm using, TeX Gyre Termes, does not seem to have this character. (Or am I wrong about that?) In any case, in order to better match the corresponding character from `pifont`, I will want to use a font other than the default one!

Comment: @murray But the question already did that: you selected it from Libertinus Math.

Comment: @murray There is a way to define an error font in LaTeX, but that’s for when it can’t find a particular font face that you specify.

Comment: So first using a `\newfontfamily` is reasonable even if only one or a couple of characters from that font is going to be used -- it doesn't overburden TeX with font families in use?

Comment: @murray Yes, it’s reasonable. Modern engines remove the limit legacy 8-bit TeX had on the number of symbol fonts.