# How to type in XeLaTeX a symbol by its unicode code?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, unicode

How to type in XeLaTeX a symbol by its code? In particular, I am interested in different dashes:

U+2011  ‑ non-breaking hyphen as hyphen (U+2010), but not an allowed line break point

U+2012  ‒ figure dash as hyphen-minus, but has the same width as digits

U+2013  – en dash used e.g. to indicate a range of values

U+2014  — em dash used e.g. to make a break in the flow of a sentence

U+2015  ― horizontal bar  used to introduce quoted text in some typographic styles; “quotation dash”; often (e.g., in the representative glyph in the Unicode standard) longer than em dash

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\len}
\begin{document}

\textemdash\ \verb|\textemdash| = \setlength{\len}{\widthof{{\textemdash}}} \the\len\\
\textthreequartersemdash\ \verb|\textthreequartersemdash| = \setlength{\len}{\widthof{{\textthreequartersemdash}}} \the\len \\
\textendash\ \verb|\textendash| = \setlength{\len}{\widthof{{\textendash}}} \the\len \\

\end{document}
```

I tried \symbol{"2012} but it yields error.

Comment: Answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32513/how-do-i-enter-an-arbitrary-unicode-code-point-into-my-document) question works for me. Apparently, you have to use `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\setmainfont{Arial}`. Of course, you can use any unicode font installed on your system

Comment: Hope this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553091/how-specify-by-unicode-number-a-particular-character-from-another-font-xelatex will helps you....

Comment: I get no error if I add `\symbol{"2012}` to your MWE. I only get a missing character message as the default font doesn't have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using U+2013 as an example as they are all the same.

`–`

Just type the character directly.

`^^^^2013`

The `^^` notation (as in classic tex but extended to 4 or 6 `^`) produces the character (as an input character) at the very earliest stage. So unlike following options can be used anywhere the character can be used eg `\^^^^2013` is `\–`

`\char"2013` (or latex `\symbol{"2013}`  which expands to same).

This  typesets as the character in the current font (if the font has that character)

`\Uchar"2013`

This  *expands*  to the character token.
So can be used in expansion only contexts such as `\typeout`.

Answer (score 3):

You can define yourself the names (I guess that TU should add these).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{NewComputerModern}
\newfontfamily{\ebgar}{EB Garamond}

\newlength{\len}

% this is not even in xunicode
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textnbhyphen}{\UnicodeEncodingName}{"2011}
% this is in xunicode
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textthreequartersemdash}{\UnicodeEncodingName}{"2012}
% the following two are in tuenc
%\DeclareTextSymbol{\textendash}{\UnicodeEncodingName}{"2013}
%\DeclareTextSymbol{\textemdash}{\UnicodeEncodingName}{"2014}
% this is in xunicode
\DeclareTextSymbol{\texttwelveudash}{\UnicodeEncodingName}{"2015}

%%% easier input
\newcommand{\entry}[1]{%
  #1 & \texttt{\string#1} & \settowidth{\len}{#1}\the\len
}


\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} l l l @{}}
\entry- \\
\entry\textnbhyphen \\
\entry\textthreequartersemdash \\
\entry\textendash \\
\entry\textemdash \\
\entry\texttwelveudash
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\ebgar
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} l l l @{}}
\entry- \\
\entry\textnbhyphen \\
\entry\textthreequartersemdash \\
\entry\textendash \\
\entry\textemdash \\
\entry\texttwelveudash
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I used NewComputerModern because it has a richer supply of glyphs than Latin Modern; not full, as you see.

I concocted myself the name for U+2011, maybe there is a better one. Possibly there is a better name also for `\textthreequartersemdash`, maybe `\textfiguredash`.

[image]