# How discover which TeXLive OpenType fonts have Unicode character with particular code?

Tags: fonts, unicode, opentype

With a main font of, say, `TeX Gyre Termes`, in a XeLaTeX document, I'm trying to find a suitable "x mark" character, namely, Unicode U+2718, from a *different* font (because the main font does not include that character).

How do I find out which OpenType fonts from TeXLive actually have that character?

(Obviously, the question generalizes to other individual Unicode characters.)

Comment: Many OpenType fonts available in TeXLive have the SIL Open Font License, and they can be found and previewed on Google Fonts. For example, Inconsolata has `U+2713`, `U+2714`, `U+2717`, `U+2718`, etc.

Comment: @RuixiZhang But how do I find out which of those fonts *do* have those Unicode glyphs? (If I go to font.google.com and search for Inconsolata, I don't see where it would tell me about those characters in that font, or how I would discover that that font has those characters!

Comment: I normally use as first try fileformat.info: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2718/fontsupport.htm

Comment: If you're on macOS, there is the free app UnicodeChecker that does what you want (for fonts installed system-wide).

Comment: You can use `otfinfo -g` and search the output for its Adobe glyph name or something like `uni1234`.

Comment: Utilities like BabelPad show which fonts have which characters, or all the characters in a text passage (Tools: Font Coverage).

Comment: @Cicada: Alas, BabelPad is Windows-only, and I long ago abandoned the Microsoft/Windows world for the Apple/Mac world.

Comment: @egreg: But I want to look only at those fonts for which there is TeXLive support, i.e., those distributed with TeXLive. So the UnicodeChecker would require copying each and every one of the TeXLive-included OTF fonts into the system font directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open up any font in a character map and check.

If you want it to be scriptable, the command `otfinfo -g` will display a list of the glyphs in any given font.  Typically, these are the Adobe font names or names like `uni1234`.

If you want to check whether a font you already loaded has it, check `\iffontchar`.

There are various websites where you can look it up for many common fonts, including `fileformat.info`.

Generally, XITS Math and STIX Two Math have a very comprehensive set of math symbols, and the Dejavu family have a very comprehensive set of text symbols.  They’re a good place to look first.

Comment: What helped, finally, was using both `getinfo -g` together with the UnicodeChecker app. And the only otf font I found with both a heavy checkmark and a heavy ballot x were LibertinusSerif-Regular.otf,  LibertinusSerifDisplay-Regular.otf, and LibertinusMath-Regular.otf.